Hello, I am new to Ubuntu and just installed 24.10 on old 2020 MBA with Sonoma OS. Can't get onboard keyboard, trackpad, or wifi to work. help
Tried looking for info here...https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi-bluetooth/#on-linux
Terminal command of modinfo brcmfmac | grep 4387   gave me:
-MacBookAir9-1:~$ modinfo brcmfmac | grep 4387
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4387c2-pcie.clm_blob
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4387c2-pcie.bin
Tried: sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-security InRelease
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Tried: sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
ynaptics
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version (1.9.2-1ubuntu3).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
grub-pc-bin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
Summary:
Upgrading: 0, Installing: 0, Removing: 0, Not Upgrading: 1
   reboot

Also tried: sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
xserver-xorg-input-all is already the newest version (1:7.7+23ubuntu3).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
grub-pc-bin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
Summary:
Upgrading: 0, Installing: 0, Removing: 0, Not Upgrading: 1
        reboot

Reboots did not resolve issue.  I am very much a beginner at this and not entirely sure of steps taking so far.

The t2linux website has instructions for installing the necessary drivers. It may also have custom Ubuntu images for macbooks. Did you check that?

Thank you for your suggestion.  I did/have been reviewing the t2linux site and am making some progress.  I appreciate your help
